# Are there any places on earth completely barren with nothing on the horizon in any direction?

Tags: where-on-earth, factoids, deserts

Imagine being on a ship in the middle of the ocean and in every direction you look, there is nothing on the horizon and everything you see is perfectly flat in every direction. Is there any desert (or other terrain) in the world that comes close to giving you that vista on land?

Comment: In other words, it wouldn't count if you could see sand dunes, even if all you see is sand in every direction?

Comment: [Ross ice shelf](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/Ross+Ice+Shelf/@-76.5432514,149.1406518,3z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1santarctic+ice+shelf!3m4!1s0xa57cf81bd37b0c9b:0xc312c065d0928e0a!8m2!3d-81.4999691!4d-174.9999732) maybe? No street view for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, that ice shelf might be a good candidate.

Comment: Sand dunes kinda count, but not really since they aren't perfectly flat.

Comment: For a place reachable for tourists, I think [Salar de Uyuni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salar_de_Uyuni) in Bolivia is as good as it gets (of course, the other tourists aren't nothing).

Comment: Salar de Uyuni is not big enough even. You can see mountains at the horizon in pretty much any direction.

Comment: The average person can see ~3mi in any direction (the horizon).  While you could probably find a number of flat 3mi circles on the Earth's surface (Bonneville Salt Flats for example) they are often surrounded by much higher relief features that would appear over the horizon.  Best bets would be the Alaskan Tundra or central Gobe.

Comment: I wonder if some places in Iceland may qualify.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **[Nullarbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullarbor_Plain)** in Australia might qualify:

[image]

(courtesy [Nullarbor Roadhouse](http://www.nullarborroadhouse.com.au))

It's a huge, completely flat and virtually uninhabited plain.  As the fake Latin name implies, there are "no trees", and there's nothing on the horizon either since there are no mountains nearby.  There are, however, some scrubby bushes and grasses, so it's not *entirely* barren.

Comment: beat me to it.  My father went on a bus trip years ago through it where the driver told everyone to look at a tree out the right hand side.  Everyone dutifully looked, wondering what was special about it. The driver then said "right, that's the last thing you'll see for the next several hundred miles, you can go to sleep now".

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Very interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

In Botswana the [Makgadikgadi Pan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makgadikgadi_Pan) qualifies, which is one of the largest salt flats in the world.

[image]

[image source](https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g472670-i17875853-Makgadikgadi_Pans_National_Park_Central_District.html)

> Lying southeast of the Okavango Delta and surrounded by the Kalahari
>   Desert, Makgadikgadi is technically not a single pan but many pans
>   with sandy desert in between, the largest being the Sua (Sowa), Nwetwe
>   and Nxai Pans. The largest individual pan is about 1,900 sq mi
>   (4,921.0 km2). In comparison, Salar de Uyuni in Bolivia is a single
>   salt flat of 4,100 sq mi (10,619.0 km2), rarely has much water, and is
>   generally claimed to be the world's largest salt pan. A dry salty clay
>   crust most of the year, the pans are seasonally covered with water and
>   grass, and are then a refuge for birds and animals in this very arid
>   part of the world. The climate is hot and dry but with regular annual
>   rains.

Answer (score 9):

There are places like that in Kazakhstan. Check http://welovemountains.net/cycling-east-part-18-aktau-riding-in-kazakhstan-pt1/ [image]

Answer (score 8):

A lot of Saskatchewan is like that (photo from [here](http://themaritimeexplorer.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Bales-under-Saskatchewan-Sky.jpg)). You can see just how flat it is from the [topo](http://www.canmaps.com/topo/nts250/map/073m.htm) maps. In some places it's yellow rapeseed (canola) to the horizons.

[image]