# Where is the longest visible line of sight on Earth from point A to point B?

Tags: where-on-earth, factoids, vantage-points

We've had some [interesting questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3666/101) on being able to see country A from B, and on [visibility for miles in every direction](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/98809/101).

For a 6 ft tall person, the horizon in a 'flat' area is meant to be about 5km. Obviously the higher you are, the further you can see, if nothing is obscuring your view.

So somewhere on Earth (point A) presumably, you can see all the way, unobscured to Point B, which is further away than any other two visible points on earth.

Where would this line be - that is, between which two points A and B?

Comment: would you be happy to exclude perpetual cloud cover?

Comment: @GayotFow I don't believe there's anywhere with *constant* cloud on earth, but for the sake of argument, let's assume no cloud.

Comment: ["I can see Russia from my house!"](http://www.snopes.com/politics/palin/russia.asp)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a list at [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20190516221621/https://beyondhorizons.eu/lines-of-sight/).

| COUNTRY | FROM | TO | KM. | AZIMUTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kyrgyzstan | Dankova (5.971 m.) | Hindu Tagh (6.436 m.) | 538 | 170º |
| Colombia | P. Cristóbal Colón (5.776 m.) | Alto Mora (3.264 m.) | 506 | 206º |

**Longest line of sight seems to be from Dankova to Hindu Tagh, 538 km in Kyrgyzstan.** Here's a [HeyWhatsThat](https://www.heywhatsthat.com/?view=D2CAW1SP) link to the winning peaks in Kyrgyzstan/China. And [another one](https://www.heywhatsthat.com/?view=C4751NKX) for the combo in Colombia.

Comment: I was surprised to see that view from Mt Everest is only #8 on that list.

Comment: @PeterM guess it gets obscured by other mountains nearby

Comment: https://www.markhorrell.com/blog/2020/what-mountain-summit-has-the-worlds-longest-view/ that "Hindu Tagh" name does not seem to exist although the peak does.

Comment: @PeterM I'm surprised it's that high.  While Everest is very high it's got a whole bunch of other high stuff around it.

Comment: This is a case of "technically correct, but probably not useful".  It's rare for the atmosphere to be clear enough to see 300 km/200 miles, and almost unheard-of to be able to see further.